# A special kind of format

Tags: two-column

I want the paper to be separated into two column. The wider one is used for the article, while the narrower one is used for comments.

The comment column need’t be filled completely but comments may be inserted at any desired vertical position.

I tried using 0-width boxes and mini pages and so on, but it has many flaws.

So how to produce such a format?

Comment: Are you talking about the marginpar contents?

Comment: that would be a single column with \marginpar (or variants such as \marginote)

Comment: Try the document class Tufte.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Where can I get ```tufte-handout.cls```?

Comment: @youthdoo It's sufficient you write document class tufte in the first line of your document.tex.